# What are the pros and cons of using Realm vs Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, realm

> Although this question might seem entirely opinion based, it would
>   serve as a great resource for future developers. (i.e. I now know
>   Firebase is severely limited when it comes to querying the database
>   but have already wasted precious time adding it to my project...)

My app currently uses `Firebase` where it downloads `JSON` data from the Firebase server, parses it and populates a `UITableView`. The user can then interact with the data locally, nothing is sent back to the server.

So far everything works fine but I've found querying the database to be a pain, and I've had to persist data locally using `Core Data`....

I've recently stumbled across `Realm` and from my understanding, it seems to provide solutions for both the server and a local database. Would there be any downsides to using it from **edge cases you've seen**? Any **problems encountered**?

I couldn't find anything recent online so Stack seemed to be the best place to ask.